Is it possible to enroll existing Azure Virtual Desktop session host to Intune?
I see the option to enrol new session hosts into Intune when creating them from the Azure portal.
Is there any way to enrol an existing session host (Windows 11 Enterprise multi-session) in Intune?
I have not been able to find any relevant information in the documentation.
